# Replace column in one file with column from another using awk?

Tags: awk

I have two files:

file1.txt:

```
111|aaa|444
222|bbb|555 
333|ccc|666
```

file2.txt:

```
111
(null)
333
```

replacing column two of file1 with column one of file2

**Expected Output**

new:

```
111|111|444
222||555
333|333|666
```

I am using the below command,
`awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}NR == FNR {a[FNR] = $B;next}$A = a[FNR]' B=1 A=2 file2.txt file1.txt > new.txt`

Output which I am getting,

new:

```
111|111|444
333|333|666
```

I am loosing the second record. how to avoid loss of record?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this as the duplicate question was deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}NR == FNR {a[FNR] = $B;next}{$A = a[FNR];print $0}' B=1 A=2 f2 f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `paste` and `cut` for this:

```
paste -d'|' <(cut -d'|' -f1 file1) <(cat file2) <(cut -d'|' -f3 file2)
```

I cannot tell which is better in terms of speed, though.