# Replace a column value in csv file from another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a csv file which has 85 fields. I want to replace column number 52nd values with the data from another file. This second file contains only 1 column and has same number of records as it is in 1st file.

e.g `data.CSV` file (1st csv file)

```
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111937,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**07822000656**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111938,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**07822000656**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111939,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**07822000656**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111939,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**07822000656**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111939,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**07822000656**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111939,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**07822000656**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
```

2nd file (contains only 1 column)

```
6228205
6225214
6225211
6225206
5206
87777
```

I want to replace

- 52nd column value (`07822000656`) from 1st file (`data.csv`) with `6228205` for 1st row in `data.csv` file
- 52nd column value (`07822000656`) with `6225214` for 2nd row
  in `data.csv` file
- 52nd column value (`07822000656`) with `6225211` for 3rd row

...and so on...

so output should be

```
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111937,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**6228205**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111938,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**6225214**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111939,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**6225211**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111939,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**6225206**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111939,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**5206**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111939,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,**87777**,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,
```

I managed to do it like below:

```
awk -F , '{$1, $2, $3, $4...$51}' data.csv >temp1.csv
awk -F , '{$53, $54, $55....$85}' data.csv >temp2.csv
paste -d "," temp1.csv 2nd_file temp2.csv
```

however, I am looking for a better way to handle this

Comment: I guess I understand what you want, but what is your question? You forgot to show your code and explain what went wrong with it.

Comment: Also, as a general rule, please only post _manageable_ extracts of data - you could easily omit most of the columns in your example `data.csv` since they are completely irrelevant to the problem, but make reading the post and assessing the relevant change more difficult.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace column in one file with column from another using awk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266716/replace-column-in-one-file-with-column-from-another-using-awk)

Comment: @AdminBee Yes...something like this but I am not getting expected output in my case
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,RA2_TT00.TTFILE00.7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111937,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,07822000656,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,|85550
0,126,,2,0,904CEE,0,0,1,0,0,,RA2_TT00.TTFILE00.7638.raw,0,0,20210515,111938,10,0,540,540,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,,,07822000655,,,07822000656,0,,,,0B020D,358605075357339 ,234307822000655,11,,01,00,0,,,0,2,1,0,1101,,1,0,23430,,,11,5,,0A03,,,0,|8545501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `awk` to construct of map of entries on the second file, keyed by line number and replace the value on the first file,

```
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR{hash[FNR]=$0; next}{$52 = hash[FNR]}1' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thank you @Inian...this worked for me. :)

Comment: As this is a general Q&A site, used as archive for others searching for the solution, I think I should add that this works in this special case, but may fail for a lots of legal `csv` files.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this question /awk, but using tools like `awk` will fail on csv files as soon as they carry a field like `"embed , in a string"`, so better use a tool designed for it, wich even makes it very simple:

```
csvtool pastecol 52 1 data.CSV value.CSV
```

This replaces column 52 of `data.CSV` with column 1 of `value.CSV`

Comment: Which csvtool is this? I googled around and there are number of projects with that name that aren't the csvtool (with pastecol) that you show. I did find this, https://colin.maudry.fr/csvtool-manual-page/, but there's no indication (out side of being a default package in Xubuntu) how to get it.

Comment: Yes, it's the one available as package for Debian, CentOS, Fedora, Ubuntu and others. The sources (it's written in OCaml) are available at https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-csv/tree/master/csvtool

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using [GoCSV](https://github.com/zacharysyoung/GoCSV), a tool designed for processing CSV.

```bsh
# Break up starting-file about column 52
gocsv select --columns 1-51 start.csv > left.csv
gocsv select --columns 53-  start.csv > right.csv

# Combine both sides with replacement column/file in the "middle"
gocsv zip left.csv replacement.csv right.csv > my_final.csv

# Prove it worked
cmp my_final.csv op_final.csv
```

I did have to dress up **op_final.csv** before doing the compare, for anyone who wants to try:

- remove OP's `**` around the target values
- add a newline, because GoCSV adds trailing newlines